# I need to read a cookie in server side before render

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server-side

I'm trying to get a cookie, which I save (httpOnly) when the user logs in. The problem comes when I recover this cookie from the server side; I send it to react and save in a reducer, but in the refresh Router process it looks like the user is not logged in. Any solutions?

Update:

express code:

```
let token = jwt.sign({
                      id: usuario.dataValues.id,
                      identifier: response.dataValues.email,
                      firma: firma
                    }, 'privatekey', (err, tk) => {
                      if (err) { console.log(err) }
                      let caducidad = 4 * 24 * 3600 * 1000;
                      const options = {
                        httpOnly: true,
                        signed: true,
                        maxAge: caducidad,
                        expires: new Date(Date.now() + caducidad)
                      };
                      res.cookie('token', tk, options).status(200);
                      res.status(200).json({ success: true, tk, user: response.dataValues })
                    })
```

React fetch:

```
export const getCookie = async () => {
 await axios.post('/api/getCookie')
    .then(res => {
        if(res.data.token && res.data.token !== undefined) {
            const user:User = jwtDecode(res.data.token);
            axios.post('/api/comprobarFirma', {id: user.id, firma: user.firma})
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.data.find) {
                        dispatch({type: 'setUser', payload: user});
                        console.log(user);
                    }else{
                        destroyCookie();
                    }
                })
        }else{
            destroyCookie();
        }
    });
```

};

Comment: Do you mean your server side router doesn't see the cookie after it's set? What server side framework are you using? Express?

Comment: Yes, Im using Express in nodejs, the server side read the cookie in the right way, the problem is that react render the router before the cookie is read.

Comment: Please, add code examples, how do you try to set and read the cookie. I'm not working with node.js, but I think it will help someone to answer.

Comment: Dont worry about nodejs, the cookie in the backend is working fine, my problem is that when I call the cookie's function, the react's router render before.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've described, you're trying to set a cookie (at some point), then have react render content based upon this cookie (either user info, authorization, or just plain-jane session tracking.

However, you're saying things like "the problem is that react render the router before the cookie is read". React can't read an httponly cookie. React is still part of the javascript framework. Setting httponly on the cookie, while safer, limits its access to the browser and the server.

Comment: You are right, react can't read an httponly cookie, but in my solution this is work of my nodejs API. The problem is that the react doesn't wait the response of the API (even if I use async/await)

Comment: Can you show us the functions of your react fetch and your express function the handles this call?